# Can we call a function from inside the setState hook function?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

Can we do something like this?:

```
const [listOfCompanies, setListOfCompanies] = setState([]);

const userChangedSth = () = > {
    setListOfCompanies((prev) => {
        const newList = generateChangedList(prev);
        changeStateInParent(newList); // 1st
        showPopup(newList);            // 2nd
        return newList;
    })
}
```

I have a strong feeling that this shouldn't be done but I lack of reasons why. Can you tell me whether 1st or 2nd function can be called here? And if not, why?

Comment: A state setter callback should be pure, no side-effects. If you need to sync with the parent or trigger a popup, a `useEffect` would be better suited.

Comment: Thanks! @EmileBergeron  Do you know why? The popup function for example, will not influence the state.

Comment: One of the reason is that React might be calling the state setter callbacks more than once, which would trigger more popup than intended in your case. A `useEffect` with the proper dependencies and logic will ensure that the popup only show up when you intended.

Comment: [React's Strict Mode](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#detecting-unexpected-side-effects) could help identify unwanted side-effects.

Answer (score 2):

Can you, sure. The more accurate question is should you though? The answer is no, you should not.

State updater functions should be pure functions, i.e. there should be absolutely no side-effects. In other words, calling the state updater function more than once with the same inputs should yield the same identical result.

React has a built-in component to help you detect unexpected side-effects.

[React.StrictNode](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html)

See specifically [Detecting Unexpected Side Effects](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#detecting-unexpected-side-effects)

> Strict mode can’t automatically detect side effects for you, but it
> can help you spot them by making them a little more deterministic.
> This is done by intentionally double-invoking the following functions:
>
> - Class component `constructor`, `render`, and `shouldComponentUpdate` methods
> - Class component static `getDerivedStateFromProps` method
> - Function component bodies
> - ***State updater functions (the first argument to `setState`)*** <--
> - Functions passed to `useState`, `useMemo`, or `useReducer`

The emphasis on the state updater function is mine. The `React.StrictMode` will double invoke the callback function.

```
setListOfCompanies((prev) => {
  const newList = generateChangedList(prev); // (1)
  changeStateInParent(newList);              // (2, 4)
  showPopup(newList);                        // (3, 4)
  return newList;
})
```

1. Is `generateChangedList` a pure function? Returns the same `newList` value given the same `prev` value?
2. Is passing the `newList` state twice to the `changeStateInParent` callback safe?
3. Do you want more than one popup possibly enqueued/shown?
4. Do we have a guarantee that the `newList` value passed out isn't mutated?
5. etc....

All side-effects should be intentional. This is accomplished by using the `useEffect` hook with an appropriate dependency. In this case, it's when the state updates.

Example:

```
const [listOfCompanies, setListOfCompanies] = setState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  changeStateInParent(listOfCompanies);
  showPopup(listOfCompanies);
}, [listOfCompanies]);

const userChangedSth = () = > {
  setListOfCompanies((prev) => {
    return generateChangedList(prev);
  });
};
```